# bootstrap model two pages

Tags: jquery, jsp, twitter-bootstrap

well I have a doubt about the bootstrap twitter, I have 2 pages, a call and another call registro.jsp index.jsp in the index.jsp there is a button that when I click a window should appear where modal registro.jsp can see but not how, I hope I can help.

Comment: Show what you've tried; if you've tried something and it's not working, then post your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use twitter bootstrap modal, you need to think in a twitter bootstrap way.

Modal is used to display an hidden div embedded in your page (index.jsp) and not an external page.

I don't think the twitter bootstrap modal is suitable for your need.